# databricks-connect not working on windows

Tags: windows, pyspark, databricks, databricks-connect

I've installed `databricks-connect` on Windows 10 with the instructions here: https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html

After running `databricks-connect configure` and entering all values, i'm running `databricks-connect test`. This is the output I'm getting, and it hangs:

```
* PySpark is installed at c:\users\user\.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pyspark
* Checking SPARK_HOME
* Checking java version
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
* Skipping scala command test on Windows
* Testing python command
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Digging a bit deeper, it seems that the underlying `pyspark` package fails to initialize. It fails on this line:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

When I try to run this manually, it hangs. I guess this is a problem is either the local Spark or the required Hadoop (and winutils.exe) installations, but `databricks-connect` requires a fresh pyspark installation (doc says to uninstall pyspark prior to installation).

Would be happy for any references for:

1. Fixing the databricks-connect issue
2. Fixing the underlying pyspark installation issue

Comment: What path is java installed into? Does it have a space in the path? If so try changing java home to use the windows short name (no spaces).

Comment: Thanks, JAVA_PATH is C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin

Comment: You may checkout the steps mentioned in the article: https://datathirst.net/blog/2019/4/20/setup-databricks-connect-on-windows